# Third degree polynomial with integer coefficient from which one is odd has no integer roots

Tags: polynomials

Third degree polynomial with integer, positive coefficient is given. Second coefficient is odd, other are even. how to prove that this polynomial has no integer roots

Comment: I don't get it. $x^3+x^2-10x+8=(x+4)(x-1)(x-2)$ has three integer roots, and the coefficient of $x^2$ is odd. What haven't you told us?

Comment: Perhaps the author of the question is referring to the coefficient on the $x$ term?

Comment: A counterexample also exists in this case (see answer below)

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false :

The polynomial $2x^3+7x^2+8x+4$ has the integer root $-2$.

If the x-term is meant to be odd, the polynomial $2x^3+8x^2+15x+14$ is a counterexample,
which also has root $-2$.